# Truncate string with EE 3

Tags: plugin, ee3, string

There used to be all kinds of plugins for EE 2 that let you shorten a variable (or any string, really), some from EllisLab as well as a number of third-party ones. Some let you specify the number of words, some were even HTML aware, etc.

What are my options at this point for working with EE 3? I haven't seen one of them converted. Do I really have to use raw PHP?

Comment: Can't you [update](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/conversion/index.html) [HTML Attribute Content](https://github.com/EllisLab/HTML-Attribute-Content) or [Word-Limit](https://github.com/EllisLab/Word-Limit) and submit a pull request?

Comment: I suppose somebody certainly could, but sadly not me, not being much of a programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to convert them for you, when I found that both [HTML-Attribute-Content](https://github.com/EllisLab/HTML-Attribute-Content/tree/master) and [Word-Limit](https://github.com/EllisLab/Word-Limit/tree/master) already have compatible branchs.

Comment: Seriously? Let me check them out.

Comment: OK, that's kind of embarrassing. Thanks anyway, accepting your answer (obviously).

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of providing additional options, check out [Streeng](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/streeng) as well.